# Reading from unordered_multiset results in crash

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, unordered

While refactoring some old code a cumbersome multilevel-map developed **in-house** was replaced by an `std::undordered_multiset`.

The multilevel-map was something like `[string_key1,string_val]` . A complex algorithm was applied to derive the keys from `string_val` and resulted in duplicate `string_val` being stored in the map but with different keys.

Eventually at some point of the application the multilevel-map was iterated to get the `string_val` and its number of occurrences.

It replaced was an `std::unordered_multilevelset` and `string_val` are just inserted to it. It seems much simpler than having an `std::map<std::string,int>` and checking-retrieving-updating the counter for every insertion.

What I want to do retrieve the number of occurrences of its inserted element, but I do not have the keys beforehands. So I iterate over the buckets but my program crashes upon creation of the string.

```
// hash map declaration
std::unordered_multiset<std::string> clevel;

// get element and occurences
for (size_t cbucket = clevel->bucket_count() - 1; cbucket != 0; --cbucket)
{
        std::string cmsg(*clevel->begin(cbucket));
        cmsg += t_str("times=") + \
                std::to_string(clevel->bucket_size(cbucket));
}
```

I do not understand what is going on here, tried to debug it but I am somehow stack( overflown ?)  :) . Program crashes in `std::string cmsg(*it);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider how `multiset` actually works as a hashtable. For example reading this [introduction](http://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/en_ca/User%20Group%20Presentations/Regina-User-Group/ShaunKaufmann-IntroHash-Sept2013.pdf) you should notice that hash maps actually preallocate their internal buckets , and the number of buckets is optimized.

Therefore if you insert element "hello" , you will probably get a number of buckets already created, but only the one corresponding to `hash("hello")` will actually have an element that you may dereference. The rest will be let's say invalid.

**Dereferencing the iterator** to the begin of every bucket results in SEGV which is your case here.

To remedy this situation you should check every time that begin is not past the end.

```
for (size_t cbucket = clevel->bucket_count() - 1; cbucket != 0; --cbucket)
{
    auto it = clevel->begin(cbucket);
    if (it != clevel->end(cbucket))
    {
        std::string cmsg(*it);
        cmsg += t_str("times=") + \
                std::to_string(clevel->bucket_size(cbucket));
    }
}
```